# How to set entity name in NHibernate ManyToOne code mapping?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

UPDATE: [Fixed in version 5.2.](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/issues/1182)

---

I'm converting a bunch of NHibernate `.hbm.xml` mappings to mapping by code. There are several `many-to-one` elements with an `entity-name` attribute:

```
<many-to-one name="Foo" column="FooId" class="Bar" entity-name="BarEntity"/>
```

which should translate to:

```
ManyToOne( c => c.Foo, map => 
{
     map.Column("FooId");
     map.EntityName("BarEntity"); // error
}
```

Unfortunately that does not work, because there is no `EntityName` in `IManyToOneMapper`. Why? Both `IManyToManyMapper` and `IOneToManyMapper` do have `EntityName`.

How do I fix this? Is there a workaround other than keeping the .hbm.xml mappings?

Comment: you should have map.ClassName property where you can add the full entity name with namespace

Comment: There is no `ClassName` property, but a `Class(System.Type entityType)` method which you can use to map to a different class, but there is no way to specify an entity name.

Comment: yes, you don't need to add entity name. by adding a class with entity name it will bind as a entity name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it just got forgotten. I just checked 4.0.2 sources and didn't find anything. Not many people actually use entity names, so it probably hadn't been requested until now.

I suggest to enter a feature request in the [jira](https://nhibernate.jira.com/secure/Dashboard.jspa). You may want to implement it yourself and provide it to the community.

Comment: Thanks, I've already [reported it as a bug](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-3860) the other day.